# Is there a way to avoid using hard coded roles in thymeleaf security?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm using a spring boot application and thymeleaf but I want to be able to secure some HTML tags with dynamic roles.

The context I have:

- Spring Boot Application connected to a identity provider so the users have their respective roles.
- The application front end is secured with thymeleaf using the roles from the identity provider but all of them are hard coded like this `<div sec:authorize="hasRole('ADMIN')">..</div>`

Everything works fine, but what if I need to secure the `<div>` with another role?, I'll have to add it manually and then redeploy the project, is this the correct approach?

I've tried having the roles in the application.properties because I can load the properties from a database, according to [this](http://www.opencodez.com/java/how-to-load-application-properties-from-database.htm) post, so If I add a new role in the database the application could load it and check it, but I can't access any property using thymeleaf security.

Comment: Well usually it's users who are going to be added dynamically, not roles. If you want to have roles in database, how would you assign it to the pages? By page name? That would probably quickly lead you to wanting a way to assign "every administration page" to that ADMIN role in database...which leads to some kind of hard-coded token that identifies this group of "administration" pages. Which is basically back to your current hard-coded roles.

Comment: The users are added with their roles in the identity provider dynamically, but for example if I have an HTML tag secured with the role "report_acces_1" but what if i need to add a new existing role in this tag?, how can I add it dynamically?. In the database I would have something like this: Registry1, HTML_TAG1, report_access_1; Registry2, HTML_TAG1, new_added_role.

Comment: And you are right, I would need to have some kind of token to identify every tag or page secured but the token will represent every group of roles from the database assigned in the HTML tags.

Comment: What I'm suggesting is you might want to research if there's a possibility to use some kind of "role groups" since it looks to me like you just need one more level of abstraction in the access management. I don't know whether that is a viable approach or not but it could be another possibility you could research.

Comment: I'm looking for the possibility to use dynamic roles with thymeleaf security.. for example: This is the hard coded way: `<div sec:authorize="hasRole('ADMIN')">..</div>` where "ADMIN" is the actual role assigned to some users, but I want something like this `<div sec:authorize="hasAnyRole(roles_variable)">..</div>` , where  "roles_variable" is a variable that contains one or more roles. So if I need a new role in this tag, I will have to add it in this variable (using a database or another source) and not directly on the thymeleaf template.